# Buscar apenas os dados de duas tabelas com diferentes id's

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Boas,

Eu tenho 2 tabelas:

Carros:

- id;
- modelo;
- comb;
- preco;

Carros_img:

- id;
- id_fk; (foreign key de Carros)
- img;

Eu faço esta pesquisa:

```html
SELECT DISTINCT carros.id, carros.modelo, carros_img.img, carros_desc.comb, carros_desc.preco 
 from carros, carros_desc, carros_img 
 where carros.id = carros_desc.id_fk 
 AND carros.id = carros_img.id_fk 
 order by carros.id ASC
```

E aparece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No id (id da tabela carros) aparece alguns id's iguais como faço para só aparecer 1 de cada tipo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Penso que o GROUP BY resolve (não testei)

```
SELECT DISTINCT carros.id, carros.modelo, carros_img.img, carros_desc.comb, carros_desc.preco 
from carros, carros_desc, carros_img 
where carros.id = carros_desc.id_fk 
AND carros.id = carros_img.id_fk 
GROUP BY carros.id 
order by carros.id ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Na tabela Carros_img deves ter varias linhas para o mesmo id mas com o campo img diferentes.

A tua query esta correta mas para aparecer so 1 linha de cada tipo , tens de  certificar que a coluna img não esta no select ou então obrigas a que apareca so um tipo de img.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT DISTINCT carros.id, carros.modelo, carros_img.img, carros_desc.comb, carros_desc.preco 
    from carros, carros_desc, carros_img 
    where carros.id = carros_desc.id_fk 
    AND carros.id = carros_img.id_fk    
        AND carros_img.img = 'smart2.jpg' -- só smart2 
order by carros.id ASC
```